# Copy file from container after the container is done

Tags: docker

I have a container that generates an mp4 file for me, which I want to download / copy to my host system after the container script has been completed.

What I managed to do is add a `sleep 2m` to the end of my `entrypoint.sh` before calling `exit 0` (it's a bit hacky, I know ) which gives me 2 minutes to run the following command to download the `mp4` file.

```
docker cp gource_container:/output/generated.mp4 ./
```

This works fine when i do it by hand, but my goal is to run it automatically via bash script.

Is there any way to `cp` the file to my host system *after* the container exits?

When I run the cp command after the container is done without `sleep` i get the following error:

```sh
$ docker cp gource_container:/output/generated.mp4 ./
Error: No such container:path: gource_container:/output/generated.mp4
```

Comment: Well. Why you don't mount your container volume to the host machine instead copy it? The file still exists in the host machine after the container is exit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A possible solution would be to mount your local working directory when creating a container from the image, and then copy the file over:

Example Dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu
RUN echo 'foo' > /foo.txt
```

Example commands:

```
# Build a Docker image and tag it test
$ docker build -t test .

# Launch a Docker container from the test image,mount the working directory to the /data directory on the container then copy the file of interest
$ docker run --rm -it -v $(pwd):/data test cp /foo.txt /data

# Inspect file locally
$ cat ./foo.txt
foo
```

Comment: What does this line do? `-v $(pwd):/data`

Comment: It mounts your working directory (`pwd`) to a volume named `data` in the container